# How to retrieve all records from a set day and set month, but a variable year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to retrieve all records after a set day and set month, but with a variable year. IE: I need to retrieve all records after October 1st, stretching 3 years backwards.

Better example: In 2019, I'd need to retrieve all records since 10/01/2016. In 2020, I'll need to retrieve all records since 10/01/2017.

I could hardcode the date, but I'd rather but not have to update the code every year.

I've been doing this for my WHERE clause but it obviously doesn't filter out records before 10/01/2016 like I need it to:
WHERE Date > DATEADD(year, -3, GETDATE());

Comment: Try `SELECT DateAdd(yy, -3, GetDate())`

Comment: Will the month and day always be 01 October? For today, would you therefore want all rows with a value more than `20161001` (`20191001` - 3 years) even though we haven't reached October yet?

Comment: WHERE Date > cast('10/01/'+ cast((datepart(year,getdate())-3) as varchar(5)) as date)

Comment: The date will always be October 1st, Yes. I just need all records from the Current date to Oct 01, (Current Year - 3 Years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Version 2012 or higher, you can use [`datefromparts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT ...
FROM TableName
WHERE DateColumn >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-3, 10, 1);
```

For older versions, you can build the date manually:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TableName
WHERE DateColumn >= CAST((CAST(YEAR(GETDATE())-3 as char(4)) + '-10-01') as date);
```

Comment: Thank you! I modified my query with the DATEFROMPARTS Solution and it produced exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for any date in a given year you want to October from 3 years ago (so for both 01 January and 31 December 2019 you would want 01 October 2016), then you could do:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE YourDateColumn >= DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())-3,10,1)
  AND YourDateColumn <= GETDATE()
  ...
```